# HIde and show elements from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

On screen load I need to hide all elements from list except ***li#active_language***.

Second step is to click on visible ***li#active_language*** element, that should open all other li elements. I tried with code below but it isn't working.

Hope that someone can help. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".jflanguageselection li:not(#active_language)").hide();
$( "#active_language" ).click(function() {
$( ".jflanguageselection li:not(#active_language)").css("display","block";).show(10000);
});
});
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<ul class="jflanguageselection">
<li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="English" title="English"></a></li>
<li id="active_language"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Deutsch" title="Deutsch"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Swedish" title="Swedish"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Serbian" title="Serbian"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. For this question that would mean at least your HTML and any relevant CSS.

Comment: why firts hide all , after show only with id or class li

Comment: If you can please check next [link](http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/de/). I have problem with language icons in top header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your site a solution is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#jflanguageselection ul.jflanguageselection li:not("#active_language")').hide();
  $('#active_language').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#jflanguageselection ul.jflanguageselection li:not("#active_language")').toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="jflanguageselection">
    <ul class="jflanguageselection">
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/en/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/en.gif" alt="English"
                title="English"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/sr/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/sr.gif" alt="Mne/Sr"
                title="Mne/Sr"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/ru.gif" alt="Russian"
                title="Russian"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/pl/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/pl.gif" alt="Polish"
                title="Polish"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/ro/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/ro.gif" alt="Romanian"
                title="Romanian"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/cz/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/cz.gif" alt="Czech"
                title="Czech"></a></li>
        <li id="active_language"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/de/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/de.gif" alt="Deutsch"
                title="Deutsch"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/it/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/it.gif" alt="Italian"
                title="Italian"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/fr/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/fr.gif" alt="Francais"
                title="Francais"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/se/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/se.gif" alt="Swedish"
                title="Swedish"></a></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/hu/"><img
                src="http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/components/com_joomfish/images/flags/hu.gif" alt="Magyar"
                title="Magyar"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is still not working. If you can please check [link](http://www.crna-gora-apartmani.com/de/)